# Using ng-repeat to access an array of objects from firebase

Tags: arrays, angularjs, object, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to access a list of notes from firebase using angularjs but having trouble displaying the data. There are no errors being thrown in the console.

```js
Notes.controller('ListGroupCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    NotesRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
      var newNotes = snapshot.val();
      console.log("title: " + newNotes.Title);
    });
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group" id="list-group" ng-controller="ListGroupCtrl">
  <!-- List of Notes -->
  <div class="list-group-item" value="" ng-repeat="note in newNotes">
    <div class="list-note-title" ng-repeat="(key, val) in note">{{key}}: {{val}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The HTML displays as:

```
<div class="list-group ng-scope" id="list-group" ng-controller="ListGroupCtrl">
  <!-- List of Notes -->
  <!-- ngRepeat: note in newNotes -->
</div>
```

The console.log line shows:

```
title: Title 1
title: Title 2
title: Title 3
```

Firebase Data:

```
Notes:

-1:
   -title: Title 1
   -content: Content 1
-2:
   -title: Title 2
   -content: Content 2
-3:
   -title: Title 3
   -content: Content 3
```

I, for now, have put the data in manually. However, I will be using Firebase's .set() which will make 1, 2, 3 randomly generated. So the data will become something like...:

```
Notes:

-QWE39Poif8uDh:
   -title: Title 1
   -content: Content 1
-78DBn2ja8skHf:
   -title: Title 2
   -content: Content 2
-11oLkdwjHf8a9:
   -title: Title 3
   -content: Content 3
```

Comment: use if(!$scope.$$phase)$scope.$apply() bdw what is NotesRef?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope` to access variables in your view.

`Notes.controller('ListGroupCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    NotesRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        $scope.newNotes = snapshot.val(); //use $scope.
        console.log("title: " + $scope.newNotes.Title);
    });
}])`

Comment: How do I access the $scope.newNotes.Title so the data is updated in the view? Currently the .list-note-title div isnt showing because the data isnt being populated by {{key}}: {{val}} correctly. I just dont know where thats breaking.

      <div class="list-group" id="list-group" ng-controller="ListGroupCtrl"> 
          <!-- List of Notes -->
          <div class="list-group-item" value="" ng-repeat="note in newNotes">
              <div class="list-note-title" ng-repeat="(key, val) in note">{{key}}: {{val}}</div>               
          </div>
      </div>

Comment: Why dont you try writing `newNotes = {{newNotes}}` in your HTML to verify if values are getting populated in `$scope.newNotes`. Don't use any `ng-repeat` here.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is, as pointed out by Frank, that you are not updating the scope when new data becomes available. You can achieve this by injecting angularjs `$timeout` into your controller. See below, an example using Firebase Litecoin exchange rates API.

HTML template

```
<body ng-controller="RatesCtrl">
  Updated:
  <pre>{{ rate._updated }}</pre>
  Data:
  <pre><span ng-repeat="(key, val) in rate">{{ key }} : {{ val }}<br></span></pre>
  Raw:
  <span><pre>{{ rate | json }}</pre></span>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('RatesCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
  var ratesRef = new Firebase('https://publicdata-cryptocurrency.firebaseio.com/litecoin');
  ratesRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    $timeout(function () {
      update(snapshot);
    });
  });

  function update (snapshot) {
    console.log('update fired');
    $scope.rate = snapshot.val();
  }
});
```

Displays and updates information just perfectly.

[image]

Related plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/SUenBO

---

Besides that, I suggest using `angular-fire` which makes your life that much easier.

HTML template

```
<body ng-controller="RatesCtrl">
  <div>
    Rate:
    <pre>Exchange rate is {{ rate.last }} at {{ rate._updated }}</pre>
    Raw:
    <pre>{{ rate | json }}</pre>
  </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['firebase']);

app.controller('RatesCtrl', function ($scope, RatesService) {
  $scope.rate = RatesService.update();
});

app.factory('RatesService', function ($firebase) {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://publicdata-cryptocurrency.firebaseio.com/litecoin');

  return {
    update: function () { 
      console.log('update fired');
      return $firebase(ref).$asObject();
    }
  };
});
```

This gives you something like

[image]
Related plunker can here http://plnkr.co/edit/QvBHRX

Comment: That tricky with `$interval` will query Firebase with `on('value'` every second, won't it. Although that may work, it's a polling solution - somewhat opposite of Firebase's server-to-client push approach.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for pointing that out. It's first time i'm using the Firebase service. Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen the data makes it into your client with the code you have. But Angular is just not aware of it, which means it doesn't update the view(s). As Mikko said in his answer, this is normally handled for you by AngularFire. In addition AngularFire will also handle the mapping from the keys that Firebase generates when you call `push` to regular array indices that Angular's `ng-repeat` prefers.

So I'd recommend using AngularFire. But until that time, this should be enough to get you one step further:

```
Notes.controller('ListGroupCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout',
  function($scope, $timeout) {
    NotesRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
      var newNotes = snapshot.val();
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.newNotes = snapshot.val();
      });
    });
  }
]);
```

Running the code in `$timeout` ensures that Angular updates any affected views afterwards.

There is nowadays a decent section on this type of [Angular-without-AngularFire interaction](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-beyond-angularfire) in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: Missed injection of $timeout, otherwise perfect.

Comment: Oops, thanks for catching that. I normally use `$scope.$apply` to accomplish the same and that doesn't require injecting a new variable. But still... fixed. :-)

Comment: I might delete my answer, since yours now covers the same solution and is more elaborate.